# Jquery : Understanding Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am following Jquery video lectures from tutsplus . in a lecture instructor  is using this code  to show/ hide  contact form on button click

```
var ContactForm = {
  container: $('#contact'),

  init: function(){
    $('<button></button>', {
      text:"Contact Us"
    })
    .insertAfter('article')
    .on('click', this.show);
  },

  show: function () {
    ContactForm.close.call(ContactForm.container);
    ContactForm.container.show();
  },

  close: function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    console.log($this);

    $('span.close').on('click',function (){
      $this.hide();
    });
  }
};
```

i am unable to get what instructor explains about few of these points so if you please help me to understand  about this syntax

```
init :function (), //  i  know about anonymous or named functions only
```

- how we can access  close/show with ContactForm.
- whats the  difference when we say this.show (in on handler) and
  `$(this).show`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, `init: function() {  }` isn't an anonymous function at all. I will try to answer the numerous parts of your question as best as possible.

`ContactForm` is an object, and thus has properties and methods that can be accessed through JS. For example, you may access the `show()` and `close()` methods from outside of the object by using its literal name, for example:

```
ContactForm.show();
ContactForm.close();
```

Since it is an object, you may also reference it by using the `this` keyword inside of it. For example, if you wanted to call the `show()` method from inside the `init()` method, you could do this:

```
var ContactForm = {
    init: function() 
    {
        this.show(); // using this keyword.
    },

    show: function() 
    {

    },

    close: function()
    {

    }
}
```

In this particular instance, `this` === `ContactForm`. However, the syntax you indicated of `$(this)` is used to create a jQuery object (or collection) from a DOMElement object. For example, let's say that you wish to bind a callback function to an element's `click` event:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {  
    $(this) // <-- This now holds a jQuery object representing the clicked element
});
```

So, bearing all of that in mind:

Within the `show()` method, the first line calls the `close()` method of the `ContactForm` object. The code makes use of the Function's prototype [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method, which allows us to specify the value of `this` inside of the function. So, on the following line:

```
ContactForm.close.call(ContactForm.container);
```

The code is sending `ContactForm.container` (which is a jQuery object) to the `close()` method, so that it may be accessed by `this`:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Inside of the `close()` method, `this` now === `$('#contact')` and **not** `ContactForm`.

Comment: Note: `var $this = $(this);` inside the original code is actually superfluous. If called from *the outside* it will not work, and from within the object (like you described) `this` is already a jQuery object. In general the code may look nice on a first glance, on closer inspection not so much.

Answer (score 1):

The init function is the function on ContactForm that you would call to hook up all this code to the DOM elements (therefore initializing the javascript).
You should be able to access it by using ContactForm.init(); in the scope where ContactForm is defined.
Same thing with the .show() and .close() functions - they should be available at ContactForm.show() from the scope where ContactForm is defined.

As the other answer mentions 'this' is referring to the scope of the current block and for example in this case with a click handler it will refer to the element being clicked. The difference between 'this' and '$(this)' is really just that the latter is wrapped in a jQuery selector, which will give you access to jQuery functions such as .show() and .hide(). Those are not available on the DOM element itself.